# Decoding escaped html data with newlines using C#

Tags: jquery, textarea, newline

I am using jquery ajax to send data from a `<textarea name="comments">`. to a server where the data will be stored in a SQL database.

If the TextBox contains

Line1
Line2
Line3,

The following string is getting passed to the server
`comments=Line1%0ALine2%0ALine3` (data encoded using javascript's `escape` function).

However, I am unable to parse this on the server ( using C# )
I tried these approaches, and none of them worked.

`(Request.Form["comments"]).Replace("\r\n","<br/>");`

`(Server.UrlDecode(Request.Form["comments"])).Replace("\r\n","<br/>");`

All suggestions welcome. I don't know where I am messing up( client side or the server side ), but it's not working. The ultimate goal is to store the data in a SQL Server Database for later retrieval.

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited in response to your edit:

%0A is \n, not \r\n

"\r\n" is *two* separate characters (ASCII 0xD and 0xA).

Change `Replace("\r\n")` to `Replace("\n")`.

Comment: Sorry for the error in the question, I've updated it now. It's actually `comments=Line1%0ALine2%0ALine3`.

Comment: oh!!. it missed my observation completely.. thank you so much!. After spending few hours, I couldn't even process the answer that you gave me initially!! I will test it and let you know. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

so based on Mud's answers, you'll need

```
(Request.Form["comments"]).Replace("\n","<br/>");
```

but would be better if you did

```
(Request.Form["comments"]).Replace("\r", "").Replace("\n","<br/>");
```

Answer (score 0):

[Microsoft.JScript.unescape](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.jscript.globalobject.unescape.aspx) is the exact equivalent. See [this blogpost](http://kseesharp.blogspot.com/2008/01/c-equivalent-of-javascript-escape.html) for more detais.

Comment: Yes, but the first line of the API docs says `
This API supports the .NET Framework infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code.`, so you should not rely on this being available in the future